# How can I avoid using a const_cast with std::vector::erase() in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, casting, constants

I have a class like this:

```
  template<class T>
  class AdjacencyList {
  public:
    void delete_node(const T&);

  protected:
    const typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator _iterator_for_node(
        const std::vector<T>&, const T&
    );
  };

  template<class T>
  void AdjacencyList<T>::delete_node(const T& node) {
    _nodes.erase(_iterator_for_node(_nodes, node));
  }

  template<class T>
  const typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator AdjacencyList<T>::_iterator_for_node(
      const std::vector<T>& list, const T& node
  ) {
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter =
        std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), node);
    if (iter != list.end())
      return iter;

    throw NoSuchNodeException();
  }
```

Apparently, `std::vector::erase()` cannot take a `const_iterator`, but `std::find()` requires one. I could cast away the `const`-ness of the iterator returned by `std::find()` when feeding it to `std::vector::erase()`, but [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889) taught me to regard `const_cast` with suspicion.

Is there another way to do this? I can't believe that something as common as removing an element from a vector should require type gymnastics. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from [my direct modification of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727264/how-can-i-avoid-using-a-const-cast-with-stdvectorerase-in-c/5727365#5727365), here's an idea:

Instead of a member function `_iterator_for_node` which

- has const issues
- is uselessly tightly bound to a particular container type (inducing a typename template resolution mess)
- does nothing more than std::find *and* throw an exception if not found

I suggest creating the following static (global/namespace) function instead:

```
template<class It, class T>
    It checked_find(It begin, It end, const T& node)
{
    It iter = std::find(begin, end, node);
    if (iter != end)
        return iter;

    throw NoSuchNodeException();
}
```

It will work with any iterator type (including non-STL, input stream iterators, forward only, const, **reverse** iterators... you name it) and it doesn't require explicit distinction between const/non const versions :)

#### With it,

a working version of your code sample would just read

```
template<class T>
class AdjacencyList {
        std::vector<T> _nodes;
    public:
        void delete_node(const T& node) 
        { _nodes.erase(checked_find(_nodes.begin(), _nodes.end(), node)); }
};
```

Note the code reduction. Always the good sign

Cheers

Comment: Code reduction is definitely a good sign. I like this idea, especially if bound to my `Graph` namespace and not the global one. :)

Comment: +1 much better than the previous one. Another solution could be to provide an `erase` template method that is actually safe to use (directly).

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you change or overload your `_iterator_for_node()` function to accept a non-const reference to the list. The reason `std::find` returns a `const_iterator` is because the list itself is `const`, and therefore `begin()` and `end()` return `const_iterator`s.

As an aside, `const_cast<>` won't actually convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator` as the 'const' is just part of the name, not a CV-qualifier.

Also, you're not technically supposed to prefix names with an underscore, as this is reserved for implementations. (it will generally work in practice)

Comment: AFAIR, it's only names prefixed with an underscore and then a capital letter that are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: I know about the naming of the class. :) I did try changing the `iterator` to a `const_iterator`, but then I needed to cast the iterator when passing it to `std::vector::erase()`, and the compiler hated that without a `const_cast`.

Comment: WRT naming private methods, is there an accepted convention? Maybe just `publicMethodsInCamelCase()` and `private_and_protected_methods_in_k_and_r_style()`?

Comment: (N3291) 17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]
1 Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
— Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.

Comment: Thus, _iterator_for_node is not reserved because it is a MEMBER function (not in the global namespace) and the 2nd character is not an upper case letter or an underscore.

Comment: @Soapbox - But isn't it silly to have a naming convention where underscore means **either** a member or a global name?

Comment: +1 - I don't understand why this wasn't the accepted answer.  The 'type gymnastics' are required only because the OP wants to erase an element from a vector that's `const` qualified.  Remove that qualifier or add an overload for non-const containers and there's no problem from the type system.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be quite some confusion between const elements, and const iterators in your code.

Without looking in to the use case, I propose the following 'fix' to make things compile:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct NoSuchNodeException {};

template<class T>
class AdjacencyList {
        std::vector<T> _nodes;
    public:
        void delete_node(const T&);

    protected:
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator _iterator_for_node(std::vector<T>&, const T&);
        typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator _iterator_for_node(const std::vector<T>&, const T&) const;
};

template<class T>
void AdjacencyList<T>::delete_node(const T& node) {
    _nodes.erase(_iterator_for_node(_nodes, node));
}

template<class T>
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator AdjacencyList<T>::_iterator_for_node(std::vector<T>& list, const T& node)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator iter = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), node);
    if (iter != list.end())
        return iter;

    throw NoSuchNodeException();

}

template<class T>
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator AdjacencyList<T>::_iterator_for_node(const std::vector<T>& list, const T& node)  const
{
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), node);
    if (iter != list.end())
        return iter;

    throw NoSuchNodeException();
}

int main()
{
    AdjacencyList<int> test;
    test.delete_node(5);
}
```

Comment: +1! There is no need to accept the vector as a reference to a const, if you use that method to modify that vector.

Comment: @deemoowoor: yes, thinking in C++ requires thinking const through. See **[my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727264/how-can-i-avoid-using-a-const-cast-with-stdvectorerase-in-c/5727594#5727594)** for a more versatile/less clumsy solution